# UNIX-based chatroom::storing each character using getch(), POSIX threads

Tags: c++, sockets, unix

all.

I am having a small issue with  unix-based chatroom which utilizes the P-thread library
and BSD sockets.

At this point, a client is able to connect to the server, login with his desired username, and 
select a room to join.
Also, messages can be sent to the server and received messages are printed to the screen correctly. 
This is all text based.

In the client program, there is the main thread which allows for the user to press characters which are then pushed onto a vector; It looks like this:

```
    std::vector<char> current_message;/*global*/
    while(1)
    {
      c = '\0';
      while(c != '\n')/*Break when enter is pressed(send message)*/
      {       
         c = my_getch();
         if((c == '\n' && current_message.size() == 0)/*Cannot send blank messages*/
             || (c == 127 && char_count == 0))
         {
            c = '\0';
            continue;
         }

         if(!my_isarrow(c))
         {
            if(c != 127)
               char_count++;
            else char_count--;
            printf("%c", c);
            current_message.push_back(c);
         }
         if(current_message.size() == 250)/*Send the message if close to buf size*/
            c = '\n';

      }
      send_message(current_message, server);
      current_message.clear();/*remove characters from already-sent buffer*/
   }
```

there is also a  thread procedure that retrieves messages from the server
 This procedure is needed because we need to allow the client to send messages,concurrently, while he is waiting for messages from the server.

The procedure looks like this:

```
void *get_messages(void *data)
{
   pthread_detach(pthread_self());/*detach the thread*/
   int *sock = (int *) data;/*the thread data passed in is actually a socket
                             which we use to retrieve messages from server*/
   while(1)
   {
      packet_t pkt;
      read(*sock, &pkt, sizeof(packet_t));/*block until a message is received*/
      for(int i = 0; i < strlen(pkt.user_name); i++)
      {
         if(pkt.user_name[i] == '\n')
            pkt.user_name[i] = '\0';
      }
      pthread_mutex_lock(&lock);

      chat_buffer.push_back(pkt);

      for(int i = 0; i < 50; i++)
         printf("\n");/*emulate clearing of terminal window*/

      for(int i = 0; i < chat_buffer.size(); i++)/*chat_buffer is a global vector*/
                                                 /*that contains all received messages*/
      {
         for(int j = 0; j < strlen(chat_buffer[i].msg); j++)
         {
            if(chat_buffer[i].msg[j] == '\n')/*remove newlines(inefficient)*/
               chat_buffer[i].msg[j] = '\0';
         }
          /*print out all received messages to the client terminal*/
         printf("%s: %s\n", chat_buffer[i].user_name, chat_buffer[i].msg);

      }
      printf("----------------------------------------------------\n");/*some formatting for readability*/
      for(int i = 0; i < current_message.size(); i++)
         printf("%c", current_message[i]);    *******This is the problem area*******
}
```

The problem in the program occurs when one client (me) has typed in some letters and they are pushed onto the buffer. And, at the same time we received a message from the server and the screen is "refreshed." You can see what is happening in the get_messages(void *) procedure. However, when this screen refreshing occurs, I don't want for my (me) client's already-typed-in letters to disappear; In order to fix this I added a line of code which prints out all letters currently in my current_message vector.
However, the letters are not printed out (Even when the code here says clearly that they should be)
Note: The characters in the buffer show up after I press some key on the keyboard.

The code for my getch() function looks like this:

```
int my_getch()/*This actually didn't come from my brain*/
{
    struct termios oldt, newt;
    int ch;
    tcgetattr(STDIN_FILENO, &oldt);
    newt = oldt;
    newt.c_lflag &= ~(ICANON | ECHO);
    tcsetattr(STDIN_FILENO, TCSANOW, &newt);
    ch = getchar();
    tcsetattr(STDIN_FILENO, TCSANOW, &oldt);
    return ch;
}
```

Also, the my_isarrow function simply parses incoming characters to see if it is an arrow key. I want to ignore arrow keys because it moves the cursor up and down(I dont want this.)

So, has anyone experienced this problem or can anyone see a problem here with which they have already dealt?

Regards,
William.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is there because stdout is a buffered stream.

You need to put an fflush(stdout) after the for loop;

An aside  fputc(current_message[i], stdout) instead of printf("%c", current_message[i]) as that's a bit more efficient:

Here is the delta that you need:

```
  printf("----------------------------------------------------\n");/*some formatting for readability*/
  for(int i = 0; i < current_message.size(); i++) {
     fputc(current_message[i], stdout);    
  }
  fflush(stdout); /* make sure that stdout is flushed, as stdout is buffered */
```

Comment: let me know if that was the actual issue ... it seems to be

Comment: yay happiness! I thought it would be the issue ( do i get a tick ? :P )